# Which comics do I need to read for the story behind Thor and Loki's new female versions?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, thor-marvel

Based on a quick internet search, the volumes involved are:

- Thor: God of Thunder, vol 4
- Thors: Battleworld
- Thor: Goddess of Thunder
- Mighty Thor: Thunder in Her Veins

These stories are about the female Thor. I'm not sure if the story of the female Loki is in here.

Did I miss any stories/volumes? If so, what are they? And is the publishing order the best one to read them in?

Also, I haven't read the Secret Wars or Original Sin storylines. How crucial are they in order to follow the plot?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is the question off-topic, duplicate, or lacks research?

Answer (score 2):

*THORS: BATTLEWORLD* isn't necessary; its story is basically about a version of Earth where Thors from dozens of alternate realities, plus alternate Thors from various points in time from the main Marvel timeline, are brought together as the world's police force. You'll gain no insight into the reasons why we now have a female Thor, and a hammerless Odinson. The other volumes you mention should cover the start of things; as of this writing, the female Thor is still the lead in *MIGHTY THOR*. The former holder of the name recently was featured in *THE UNWORTHY THOR* (a 5 issue mini-series).

The female Loki story dates from a few years ago. It's covered in J. Michael Straczynski's run on *THOR*. That's covered in various formats; I believe there's an omnibus, but it's also available in trade paperback.

The female Loki also played a major role in *MIGHTY AVENGERS*. That story is completely unnecessary to follow the main storyline, but is mentioned for the sake of completeness. In addition, she was a part of Norman Osborne's Cabal (a semi-villainous version of the Illuminati, as seen in *NEW AVENGERS*.

- Main story:

  - Collected:

    - *THOR by J. Michael Straczynski* v. 1-3
  - Individual issues:

    - *THOR* (2007) 1-12, 600-603
    - *THOR: GOD-SIZED FINALE*
- Also appears in:

  - Collected:

    - *MIGHTY AVENGERS: EARTH'S MIGHTIEST*
    - *MIGHTY AVENGERS: THE UNSPOKEN*
    - *SIEGE: MIGHTY AVENGERS*
  - Individual issues:

    - *DARK REIGN: THE CABAL*
    - *MIGHTY AVENGERS* (2007) 21-36